# Run multiple python programs at once

Tags: python, pi-2

How can I run multiple programs in python at once, I am using the Python IDLE to edit and run programs. I want to run a program for the pi camera and my character lcd screen at the same time... But one stops when the other starts.

How can I do that?

Comment: Hello and welcoming. I have put your question on hold as it is a general programming question not specific to the Pi, see [what's on-topic](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15329649/how-to-run-two-modules-at-the-same-time-in-idle). You can open more than one IDLE at a time. so open one, run the first program, then open the second, and run the second program.

Alternatively you can (and should) use the command line for this. All you would have to do is:

```
python /path/to/firstprogram.py &
python /path/to/secondprogram.py &
```